# How do I get the next available unique ID in Rails without calling Model.last.id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I populated a database, then deleted all the users. Now I need to get the next available ID (the last one used was 109, but I need this to work in any situation where this happens, not just my unique one) without calling Model.all.last. Is this possible, and how do I do it?

Comment: This is database-specific, there isn't likely a way to do this through ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create the table for an ActiveRecord `Model` class, you'll get a table called `models`. The `id`s for this table will be a [`serial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column which gets its values from the `models_id_seq` sequence. You can get the last value that this sequence generated with this:

```
select last_value from models_id_seq
```

so all you need is a simple [`select_value`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-select_value) call:

```
last_id = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
                            .select_value('select last_value from models_id_seq')
                            .to_i
```

Keep in mind that you will run into trouble is something else is working with your table while you're trying to find the last `id` value. This is also PostgreSQL-specific but you've tagged this with [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Simplify with "select_value":
last_id = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_value('select last_value from models_id_seq').to_i

Answer (score 0):

To do it dynamically I'd say your best bet is to store the value in another table. You could do this with a [trigger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger) that updates the field each time a record is added. This method does not rely on your rails app so it is probably a better way than doing it in ruby.

Also, If you just need it occasionally for manual updates, I know if you are using something like phpmyadmin you can get the value by looking in the table structure at the bottom it will say "Next autoindex".